# Use of #error directive in include guards

Tags: c++, c, include-guards

I have just stumbled upon a project in which the include guards of every header file look like this:

```c
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

/* Code */

#else
#error "Multiple inclusion of file a.h"
#endif
```

Is there an actual usecase for having an `#error` directive there? It looks like it kills the purpose of having an include guard at all.

The code compiles and works perfectly when removing the `#else`-`#error` directives.

Comment: Looks like a way to warn the programmer to remove "unneeded" includes. But this is an antipattern. Each file *should* include everything it needs directly, even if one knows there are some indirect inclusions.

Comment: To me it looks like remains of some debug code that wasn't properly cleaned up before release.

Comment: There's belt-and-suspenders coding (which is sometimes perfectly appropriate), but this is more like a belt-and-capital-punishment-for-inadvertent-butt-flashing level of rulemongering.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an actual usecase for having an #error directive there?

Possibly. But it's not typical.

> It looks like it kills the purpose of having an include guard at all.

Indeed. Having the error directive makes the include guard redundant.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an actual usecase for having an #error directive there?

Yes. I created such headers for my project.

My goal was to create a header that defines macros, and another header that undefines them.

For example:

`define.h`:

```
#ifndef DEFINE_H
#define DEFINE_H
    // We can now include undef.h
    #undef UNDEF_H
    #define FWD(...) static_cast<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)&&>(__VA_ARGS__)
    
    #define EXPR(...) \
        noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
        -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) { \
            return __VA_ARGS__; \
        }
    
    #define LIFT(func) [&](auto&&... args) EXPR(func(FWD(args)...))
#else
    #error "A previous header leaked the macros"
#endif
```

`undef.h`:

```
#ifndef UNDEF_H
    // Can include define.h again
    #undef DEFINE_H

    // Have to include define.h to include undef again
    #define UNDEF_H

    // Undef macros
    #undef FWD
    #undef EXPR
    #undef LIFT
#else
    #error "Undef must be paired with define"
#endif
```

That way, you must include define before your code (after all other includes) and include `undef.h` at the end of the header file, and they always have to be paired.

> It looks like it kills the purpose of having an include guard at all.

Depends on how you want to protect your headers. If that `a.h` is only meant to be included by that project (as a private header) and the project has a specific location that includes it, it should not be a problem if all other include guards are correct.

For example:
`b.h`

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
#include "a.h"
#endif
```

If you include `b.h` multiple time, `a.h` is only included one time and no errors occurs.

Comment: I think it begs the question - what is the use-case of requiring headers to be "paired"?

Comment: We could say it makes sense if you want to make paired headers like in your example, even though I don't see the point of having such paired headers to begin with. As for the project I'm talking about, I guess it's just an ignorant application of include guards, since that pattern of directives is used in every header file.

Comment: @EugeneSh. having headers not leaking macros with generic names, and enforcing the inclusion pattern.